# Magento using both radio button and check box

Tags: magento

[Please this link to see picture!](https://scontent-a-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/t1.0-9/p320x320/1606858_606151176142040_8736104622285400966_n.jpg)

This screenshot is from products view of www.templatemoonster.com .
I want to use both radio button and check box as shown in figure.
I find through the internet. I found out some instruction. 
Like this.

MAGENTO: ADD RADIO/CHECKBOX BUTTON IN CUSTOM COLUMN IN ADMIN GRID

Radio button:

```
 $this->addColumn('some_id', array(
        'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
        'header' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Some Header'),
        'type' => 'radio',
        'html_name' => 'items[]',
        'align' => 'center',
        'value' => array('1')
    ));
```

Checkbox:

```
$this->addColumn('some_id', array(
    'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
    'header' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Some Header'),
    'type' => 'radio',
    'field_name' => 'items[]',
    'align' => 'center',
    'values' => array('1', '2') ));
```

Further, in Form.php you can add this below code to have by default behavior and onclick behaviour:

```
$fieldset->addField('some_id', 'checkbox', array(

        'label' => Mage::helper('magentostudy_news')->__('Featured'),
        'name' => 'featured',
        'value' => 1,
        'checked' => ($model->getFeatured() == 1) ? 'true' : '',
        'onclick' => 'this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;',
        'disabled' => false,
        'readonly' => false,
    ));
```

But I don't know how to use it and can you tell me any solution if you have alternative ways.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned above, the solution you found is used for only *admin grid*. They are created as `Varien_Data_Form`. But we do not know how the form that used in your example was created.

You can try to find it out by checking checkboxes in `System -> Configuration -> Developer -> [change Current Configuration Scope to Main Website] -> in section Debug` set Template Path Hints and Add Block Names to Hints to Yes.

Then you can see on the page that you specified block and template names. After that, you should check in a block that you've seen on the previous step how does the form was created. Probably it was created as `Varien_Data_Form` - so you can try to add the column as you specified before.

If the form was not created a right way, probably you can add your field in the template (you've seen that name in the place that was specified near the block name) as regular html-code.